# Are Statefull widget deleted and replaced when being rebuild using setState()?

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

As per my inforamtion,

flutter has a widget tree and an element tree.
For every stateful widget in the widget tree an element in the element tree is created with state object attached to it, that is pointing at the widget and which rebuilds the widget when we call setState(), by destroying it and replacing with a new widget.

If the widget is destroyed, then where is all the widget configuration held until new widget is replaced instead of the old one?

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 trees : Widget Tree, Element Tree and Render Object Tree.

watch this:

[How Flutter renders Widgets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996ZgFRENMs&t=1171s&ab_channel=Flutter)

Answer (score 0):

the widget is not really destroyed if you call setState

only on the screen the widgets was destroyed if you call setState

Comment: But as i have known, the state object simply point to another object of that widget. That means it destroyes the old one. And Creates new one with same configurations. again, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: that's correct - but that's not your question